# How to solve $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I know that the limit doesn't exist, using Fixed Point Iteration Method and some appropriate inequalities. I can't think of any way to find the explicit form for $a_n$ from the following recurrence relation.
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$$

(If this can be solved, then can $a_{n+1}=ka_n+\frac{l}{a_n}$ be solved?)

Comment: Oops. I meant to say that. (Just edited it.)

Comment: It is a pitty you did not ask for $a_{n + 1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n} + \frac{1}{a_{n}})$. Just for curiosity, have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928503/characteristic-equation-of-a-recurrence-relation/1928507#1928507

Comment: Precise asymptotics can be computed, but not a closed form. (And this was asked previously on the site.)

Comment: Do we know for certain that the closed form doesn't exist?